# Как объединить два qtextedit и записать в файл .odt?

Tags: c++, qt, filewriter

У меня слишком большой текст и поэтому выдаёт ошибку C1091: compiler limit: string exceeds 65535 bytes in length. Я решил разбить эту строку на две части и поместить в qtextedit? То есть у меня есть :

```
 QTextEdit* TextEdit = new QTextEdit("...<P ALIGN=JUSTIFY STYLE=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in\"><BR><BR>"
                                        "</P>"
                                        "<P ALIGN=JUSTIFY STYLE=\"margin-bottom: 0.14in\"><BR><BR>"
                                        "</P>...");

 QTextEdit* TextEditOne = new QTextEdit("...<P>Какой то текст</P>...";
```

Как мне взять две части текста из двух QTextEdit  и записать в один файл ?
Я делаю так :

```
QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Файл ODT"),"",tr("Файлы ODT (*.odt)"));
if (fileName.isEmpty()) return;

QTextDocumentWriter writer(fileName);
QTextDocument *m_document = new QTextDocument();
bool success;
m_document=TextEdit->document();
m_document+=TextEditOne->document();

success = writer.write(m_document);
if (success)
{
   QMessageBox::information(this, "Отлично!", "Экспорт прошел успешно");
}
else
{
   QMessageBox::critical(this, "Ошибка", "При сохранении файла произошла ошибка");
}
```

Но у меня постоянно выскакивает сообщение :При сохранении файла произошла ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Запишите весь свой текст в файл, файл добавьте в ресурсы и уже с ресурсов читайте и записывайте куда Вам надо.

Comment: Пример можно ? Мне надо автоматически добавлять в этот файл данные из базы